# Receiving AWS Network Error when trying to enable Amplify Studio

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

Really stumped right now. I want to use Amplify for a Cloud assignment and have done `amplify init` in VS Code terminal to create the app. Unfortunately, I've been receiving this error when I try to enable Amplify Studio via the AWS webpage.

[image: Network Failure]

I thought my roles and permissions might need to be adjusted but I have `AdministratorAccess-Amplify` on the users I need. I also couldn't delete any of my test applications due to a similar error, but I managed to delete them via the CLI with no issues.

So my question is, is there any way to enable Amplify Studio via the CLI, or has anyone run into this issue before and been able to fix it?

Thanks in advance.

:)